# Integrate AT_GIS_GRID (NTv2 Transformation) in QGIS 2.8 & 2.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8, qgis-2.10

[image]Compared to previous versions in QGIS 2.8/2.10 no *.gsb-Files seem to be referenced in srs.db (for NTv2 Transformations) - did the system of using NTv2 change after QGIS 2.2 ? Wanted to integrate AT_GIS_GRID in 2.10 like described here: http://isticktoit.net/?p=371
QGIS 2.8/2.10 (Win64) do not allow to edit srs.db and p1 not able to save character-values like AT_GIS_GRID.gsb

[image]

Comment: I tried the workflow, and it works for me. I edited the database with spatialite:gui while QGIS is closed. The p1 column already contains other gsb files in the last rows. Can you describe more detailed what you did and what does not work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the problem is a "readonly-database". Added a Screenshot

Comment: Can you check in the Windows explorer if it is set readonly by the OS, do you have the rights to change that, or is it used by some other process (like running QGIS in the background)? I did not get that message. Maybe you need to have full read+write access for the whole C: drive.

Comment: Looks like a problem on Windows (enterprise installations). The file itself has all rights (r+w), but the directory not and that seems to be the problem. Doing the same on Linux as sudo works well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem on Windows (enterprise installations). The file itself has all rights (r+w), but the directory not and that seems to be the problem. Doing the same on Linux as sudo works well.
QGIS PlugIn NTv2-Transformations will try to integrate AT_GIS_GRID: https://github.com/NaturalGIS/ntv2_transformations/issues/10